# Using Scipy.interpolate.splev to extrapolate to fill missing data Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, extrapolation

I'm trying to use extrapolation to get data for some missing numbers and am really struggling.

Below is some options data with the strike price as the index and the volatility as `MidVol`. What I'm trying to do is find the `MidVol` for various strikes that aren't listed, such as the 2000.0, 3000.0 or the 30000.0 or 40000.0.

```
         MidVol    CallDelta PutDelta
4000.0   0.757832  0.910918 -0.089082
5000.0   0.739650  0.844523 -0.155477
6000.0   0.742915  0.766228 -0.233772
7000.0   0.733530  0.685637 -0.314363
8000.0   0.753219  0.610900 -0.389100
9000.0   0.750366  0.539006 -0.460994
10000.0  0.756793  0.476428 -0.523572
11000.0  0.774761  0.426470 -0.573530
12000.0  0.781004  0.379058 -0.620942
14000.0  0.795634  0.303317 -0.696683
16000.0  0.812305  0.247911 -0.752089
18000.0  0.831367  0.207874 -0.792126
20000.0  0.852848  0.179159 -0.820841
```

I have used both `poly1d` and `interp1d` to draw a curve for the current data, and as `interp1d` is the only one that seems to have an extrapolation feature you'd think that would be a good one to use. The code I have for that curve is:

`curve = interp1d(df.index, df['MidVol'], kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')`

And then would use the following code to calculate the missing strikes:

```
missing = [20000, 22000,24000,26000,28000,30000]
extrap = [f(x).item() for x in sample]
```

However, when I then try to extrapolate out and get data for point that aren't in the `df` I get this joke of a response:

[image]

Firstly, does anyone know why the extrapolation is failing miserably? The 30000.0 strike should have a `MidVol` of around 0.95.

I have since stumbled across `scipy.splev` which actually fits the data even better than `interp1d` in my opinion. And the code I use for that is:

```
ipo = spi.splrep(df.index, df['MidVol'], k=5, s=6)
iy = spi.splev(df.index, ipo)
```

I also noticed that there was a `ext` variable in the documentation which says `if ext=0, return the extrapolated value.`. Does this mean I can use this to extrapolate out? If so can any one explain how I do that in a similar manner to how I do it above with `missing = [20000, 22000,24000,26000,28000,30000]` and then calculate the `MidVol` for each missing strike?

If anyone can shed light on either of my problems (why `interp1d` doesn't extrapolate properly or how to extrapolate with `splev`) I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: *"Firstly, does anyone know why the extrapolation is failing miserably?"* You used the argument `kind='quadratic'`, and those extrapolated curves look like parabolas, as you requested!

Comment: Oh sorry fair enough, it was from an answer I got from here and the resulting graph looked exactly what I wanted. I changed to 'cubic' and the graph is even worse. Is there another 'kind' I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

You can somewhat control the extrapolation mode with `make_interp_spline` or `CubicSpline` bc_type parameter. E.g. you can force a linear extrapolation with bc_type="natural".